# how to remove rows with all NULL values in R

Tags: r, unique

I have the following matrix:

```
id A    B    C
1  1    2    5
2  4    6    7
3  NULL NULL NULL
4  NULL 4    6
```

I will like to remove just the row with id 3. Note that when I use `unique()` it is still kept because id is unique per se.

Comment: It is not possible to have `NULL` values in a normal column.  Do you have a `list` column or `"NULL"` (character)

Comment: I think I have a list column.... it is definitely not a character

Comment: In that case, the solution I posted should work.  I created a small reproducible example, but not sure if that is the correct structure you have.  Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the columns are `list` because `NULL` would not exist in a `vector`.  If that is the case

```
i1 <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[-1], function(x) sapply(x, is.null)))
df1[!i1,]
#   id A B C
#1  1 1 2 5
#2  2 4 6 7
#4  4   4 6
```

---

If the `NULL` is a character `"NULL"`, an option is

```
i1 <- rowSums(df1[-1] == "NULL") == ncol(df1[-1])
df1[!i1,]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:4, A = I(list(1, 4, NULL, NULL)),
     B = I(list(2, 6, NULL, 4)), C = I(list(5, 7, NULL, 6)))
```